# Warning : tempnam() [<a href='function.tempnam'>function.tempnam</a>]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect

Tags: images, permissions, pdf

When generating PDF with dompdf I am having this problem in pdf file when viewing file in notepad

> Warning :  tempnam() [function.tempnam]:
>   SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The
>   script whose uid is 10210 is not
>   allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0
>   in
>   **/var/www/vhosts/www.mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysite/dompdf/include/image_cache.cls.php**
>   on line **105**
>
> Warning:  file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]:
>   Filename cannot be empty in
>   **/var/www/vhosts/www.mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysite/dompdf/include/image_cache.cls.php**
>   on line **117**
>
> Warning:  unlink() [function.unlink]:
>   Unable to access  in
>   **/var/www/vhosts/www.mysite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysite/dompdf/include/image_cache.cls.php**
>   on line **153**
>   Blockquote

I have included image in pdf file. Without image this message is not displayed. I have tried with absolute and relative path of the image also but did not work. I have set the folder permission to 777 to dompdf folder. Need help on this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should rename the title of your question to something comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off PHP Safe Mode, or get your host to do it for you. Lots and lots of things won't work in safe mode.

C'mon. Live on the edge. That's where the fun is. :)

Answer (score 1):

In dompdf_config.inc.php file there is a line

```
//define("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", "/tmp");
```

I changed this as `define("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", DOMPDF_DIR."/tmp");` and created folder tmp within folder dompdf and this worked for me.

Thank you all for your concern :)

Comment: Hi user478, thanks for answering your own question, you just saved me several hours with this fix :-)